# Installed elasticsearch using homebrew and cannot locate the config files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, path, elasticsearch, homebrew

I installed elasticsearch using homebrew and I want to make some configurations to it but I can't find the folder it was installed to.  I'm looking for the configuration files as state [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/configuration.html).  Using rails 3.1.1  Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

While @karmi's answer gets you most of the way there, you'll actually need to look at the .plist that is linked when you install via homebrew and follow the (LaunchAgent instructions)

```
more ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist
```

Will produce some output that includes the important line:

```
es.config=/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.20.5/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 127):

Just type `brew info elasticsearch`, it should print you all the paths.

Comment: Actually, this currently doesn't show you where the config file is located, but is still useful in showing where the data-dirs are.

Comment: Argh, the `caveat` has been changed in Homebrew, it's a shame it doesn't show the config location...

Comment: Ii shows the config location (on Mac): 
    `Config:  /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/`
So config is here: 
    `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

Comment: As of now it definitely shows the directory of config:
==> Caveats
Data:    /opt/homebrew/var/lib/elasticsearch/
Logs:    /opt/homebrew/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
Plugins: /opt/homebrew/var/elasticsearch/plugins/
Config:  /opt/homebrew/etc/elasticsearch/

Answer (score 15):

On my macOS it's located here:

```
/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

And on Windows it should be here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config\elasticsearch.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version (5.6.3) it is located at /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/5.6.3/libexec/config/ealasticsearch.yml